# updating UIImageView creates memory leak

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, imageview

I have researched hundreds of posts, but still cannot figure out where my problem is. I have an array of image names and I'm trying to randomly select an image and update the imageview on an event. When run on my device it crashes after 12-15 images.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:@"IMG_0006.JPG",
                        @"IMG_0007.JPG",
                        @"IMG_0008.JPG",
                        @"IMG_0034.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0036.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0043.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0062.JPG",
                        @"IMG_0069.JPG",
                        @"IMG_0076.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0093.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0096.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0168.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0240.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0251.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0262.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0264.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0310.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0351.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0355.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0391.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0404.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0417.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0428.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0461.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0471.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0485.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0492.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0550.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0568.jpg",
                        @"IMG_0822.jpg", nil];

    [self makePrediction];
}


- (void) makePrediction {
    NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.predictionArray.count);

    [self.pageImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.predictionArray objectAtIndex:index ]]];

}


-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self makePrediction];
}
```

Comment: Please, show us some code so we can help you.

Comment: code looks ok, i wonder if you have a corrupt or missing image. I suggest you NSLog to see if the crash is always caused by the same image. If so remove that one from your list and see if it runs ok without it.

Comment: I checked with NSLog and all the files are there. Also, it doesn't crash with the simulator, just on the device. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the **imageNamed:** method to set the image of the imageview.But problem is **imageNamed:** method who has its own caching mechanism that you dont have any control over it.So when & where the allocated memory is released we don't know.So instead of using **imageNamed:** method use the following method to set the image.

```
NSString* imgpath= [ [ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"png"];

imgviw.image = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imgPath];
```

The main advantage of using the **imageWithContentsOfFile:** method is this method does NOT cache the image, and therefore does not cause any memory issues with retaining large images. Also before applying image to imageview you can set the `imgviw.image = nil` & then set the image to avoid the memory leaks problems